# Problem setting up postgres

Tags: postgresql

So I am trying to connect to freshly installed postgres. Whenever I try to create a database or use any commands nothing happens.

for example
`postgres=#`
changes to `postgres-#` after running a command, screenshot below as example:

how can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: If the `=#` prompt changes to `-#`, it means you've forgotten to end the statement with a semicolon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, as with any other SQL database, you must end each SQL statement with a semicolon. In your screenshot, both `create database test;` and `select * from postgres;` must be terminated with a semicolon, as I have done.

Comment: It is `psql`, not SQL, that needs the semicolon. In SQL, you need not end a statement with a semicolon (try `psql -c 'SELECT 42'`), you only need a semicolon as a separator if you have several statements in a single line.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The semicolon is also needed in SQLite, MySQL, Oracle, DB2 and every other SQL database I've ever used. That it isn't required by the language itself is, I think, splitting hairs.

Comment: That's why I put it as a comment. I wanted to point out that there is a significant difference to languages like C, where the semicolon is required at the end of a statement. It isn't required in SQL. Only in `psql`. Anyway, I upvoted your answer, because it solves the problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Fair enough.